# Renumbering pages in tufts-book class

Tags: page-numbering, tufte

I am just starting to use the tufts-latex style. It numbers the pages from the very first page, though only displays them at the start of chapter 1. Is there a way to force it to start the number with page 1 at the start of chapter 1?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you would want to do this but the following code will prevent numbers being printed for the front matter and will make the numbering start at 1 with the first chapter. Note that killing numbering altogether results in warnings because I guess `tufte` loads `hyperref` which wants unique page identifiers. So just not printing them and giving them numbers in a different system seems to work better.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter\pagenumbering{roman}\pagestyle{empty}
    \kant[1]

    \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter\setcounter{page}{1}\pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{A first chapter}
    \kant[2]
    \section{A section}
    \kant[3]
    \chapter{A second chapter}
    \kant[4-5]

\end{document}
```

will produce:

[image: Numberless pages (for some reason)]

Resetting the counter is probably unnecessary since `\pagenumbering{arabic}` usually does this anyway but I'm not certain what all `tufte` redefines....